# How can I use Ninject in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.1

I've registered my modules in the stratup.cs and I want to use the dependency injection without using arguments in the constructor.

```
public class AdherentManager
{
    private readonly IAdherentRepository _adherentRepository;

    public AdherentManager()
    {
        _adherentRepository = // how can i inject without using the arugments. 
    }

    public void AddAdherent(Adherent pAdherent)
    {
        _adherentRepository.Insert(pAdherent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to instantiate in your constructor

_adherentRepository = new IAdherentRepository();

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not usefull for the depenency injection.